# How do i get the Facebook like button to link with various news posts?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, permalinks

Can anyone help me solve a Facebook "Like Button" issue I'm having?

I have installed this plugin on my website and would like the button to corresponded with each of my different news post separately. At the moment it only links to my websites home page. The footer which features at the bottom of each post has been set up as a PERMALINK.

Website link - http://www.estrellarocks.com/news

Below is the code i'm using:

```
<head>
<title>Estrella</title>

<meta property="fb:admins" content="......"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="......"/>

<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://estrellarocks.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Estrella Official"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Official Website for Scottish rock band Estrella!"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://estrellarocks.squarespace.com/storage/FB%20Plugin%20image.jpg"/>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '.......', 
      channelUrl : '//www.estrellarocks.com/channel.html', 
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true, 
      xfbml      : true   
    });

  };


  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));


</script>
</body>
</head>
```

My PERMALINK:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="%PERMALINK%" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```